# Ansible not executing rds_instance task due to wrong variable evaluation

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, ansible, amazon-rds

I am struggeling with ansible since a task defined a playbook is not being executed to manage an AWS rds instance.

This is the command I execute within an jenkins pipeline:

state: "running"

identifier: "myDatabase"

```
 sh "ansible-playbook ${env.WORKSPACE}/cost-optimization/ansible/manage_rds.yml --extra-vars 'instanceState=${state} identifier=${dbsIdentifier}'"
```

The playbook looks like this:

```
manage_rds.yml:
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    rdsState: "{{instanceState}}"
    rdsIdentifier: "{{identifier|lower}}"

  tasks:

    - name: "Starting RDS instances"
      rds_instance:
        state: running
        db_instance_identifier: "{{ rdsIdentifier }}"
        wait: yes
      register: rds_result
      when: rdsState == "running"


    - name: "Stopping RDS instances"
      rds_instance:
        state: stopping
        db_instance_identifier: "{{ rdsIdentifier }}"
        wait: yes
      register: rds_result
      when: rdsState == "stopped"


    - name: Show RDS result
      debug:
        var: rds_result

    - import_tasks: tasks/task_create_partial_report.yml
      vars:
        identifier: "{{rdsIdentifier|lower}}"
        partial: "db"
```

I expect the AWS RDS instance is being spinned up.
Instead the result looks like this:

```
TASK [Starting RDS instances] **************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Stopping RDS instances] **************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Show RDS result] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "rds_result": {
        "changed": false, 
        "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False", 
        "skipped": true
    }
}
```

Any idea how to solve this?

EDIT:

I followed the recommendation from below.
However, the RDS instance is still not affected:

```
    + ansible-playbook /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/.../ansible/manage_rds.yml --extra-vars 'instanceState=running identifier=myDatabase'
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Starting RDS instances] **************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Show RDS result] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "rds_result": {
        "allocated_storage": 20, 
        "associated_roles": [], 
        "auto_minor_version_upgrade": false, 
        "availability_zone": "eu-central-1a", 
        "backup_retention_period": 21, 
        "ca_certificate_identifier": "rds-ca-2015", 
        "changed": false, 
        "character_set_name": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS", 
        "copy_tags_to_snapshot": true, 
        "db_instance_arn": "arn:aws:rds:mydatabase", 
        "db_instance_class": "db.t2.micro", 
        "db_instance_identifier": "mydatabase", 
        "db_instance_port": 0, 
        "db_instance_status": "stopped", 
        "db_parameter_groups": [
            {
                "db_parameter_group_name": "....-sqlserver-ex-14-00", 
                "parameter_apply_status": "in-sync"
            }
        ], 
...
```

So the state remains stopped althoug it is set to running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`register` will register the result of a task, what ever that is even, if it is skipped.

In your case, you run the first task `when: rdsState == "running"`, register the result of that successful run and immediately override your registered var with a skipped task result.

There are several solutions to go other this. I'll just give 2 out of my hat here:

1. **Debug the var after each task**

You could add the following task after each `rds_instance` call

```
    - name: Show RDS result
      debug:
        var: rds_result
      when: rds_result is not skipped
```

That would only print out after each task if it was actually run.

2. **Run a single parameterized task**

You need a mapping between your variable value and the one expected in the module params. Add the following to your vars:

```
    my_rds_state:
      running:
        name: started
        description: Starting
      stopped:
        name: stopped
        description: Stopping
```

Then you can have a single task that will do the job whatever the param:

```
    - name: "{{ my_rds_state[rdsState].description }} RDS instances"
      rds_instance:
        state: "{{ my_rds_state[rdsState].name }}"
        db_instance_identifier: "{{ rdsIdentifier }}"
        wait: yes
      register: rds_result

    - name: Show RDS result
      debug:
        var: rds_result
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This looks much cleaner and I learned something new. However the task is still not being executed properly. Only when I hardcode the "state" and "db_instance_identifier" the rds instance will be started or stopped.

Comment: try `--extra-vars "instanceState=${state}" --extra-vars "identifier=${dbsIdentifier}"` (repeat the option don't pass all vars in one go)

Comment: Same issue. Ansible does not trigger the instance to start up.

Comment: And when you hardcode `"{{ rdsIdentifier }}"` it does ?

Comment: No. Not even this does work. Pretty strange. Do you have an idea how to debug this?

Comment: So that is a totally different question :) Your actual problem is solved (showing the result of your task correctly). You should ask a new question for this.